# how to declarer input type file in react form hook using controller when I put value controller default its not working

Tags: reactjs

I just want to know how to declare value of file in react form hook my codes are here

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="file"
  rules={{ required: "this field is required*." }}
  render={({ field }) => (
          <TextField
           id="file"
           label="your resume in pdf"
           variant="outlined"
           placeholder="Enter Your Nick Name"
           fullWidth
           margin="normal"
           type="file"
           InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
           inputProps={{ accept: "application/pdf" }}
           {...field}
           error={Boolean(errors?.file)}
           helperText={errors.file?.message}

           />

         )}
/>
```

please help me